# If I unjoin a community, can I rejoin it later?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, user-accounts, communities-list

I'm wondering about what happens when I remove myself from a community.  I know how to do it (under "Edit Profile & Settings"), but I'm wondering if I'd be able to rejoin that community later or if unjoining is instead a permanent action.

(Note: I know that this may seem like a duplicate question, but it's not quite the same as any question that I can find.  No question about removing oneself from a community addresses rejoining later.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can rejoin later.  (Source: I did it several times, including on this site.)

Try not to abuse the new existence by upvoting the posts from the old account (not sure if anyone would care about upvotes given to a deleted user, since they do not generate reputation, but it might be seen as abuse).

Comment: Just curious, is the association bonus reawarded again?

Comment: In that community, yes.

Comment: Note that you can't remove your account yourself once you had interacted with the site in a way (posted / voted) - the "delete profile" button will no longer be here.

Comment: @nicael One post is okay. Two posts, or any kind of votes, remove the button.

Comment: Perfect!  That definitely answers my question.  Thanks!